# Joining columns with different types

Tags: sql

Can I join a column of a table that is an Integer type with a column of another table that is a BigInteger type? If so, would I need to cast or add anything special?

Comment: Why don't you try it???

Answer (score 1):

In general, SQL engines will do a conversion between `bigint` and `int` silently.  I'm pretty sure that most will convert the `int` to a `bigint`.  It is possible that your particular database might choose to convert both to `int` -- leaving open the possibility of an overflow error.

Often, conversion of types prevents the use of indexes.  This can have a serious performance impact, if the index is needed.

Otherwise, there is no logical issue.  Except.  Most `join`s are on foreign keys.  Foreign keys should be properly declared -- and they need to have the same type.  So, you might want to investigate your data model, because in a proper data model, this would almost never be a question that needs to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I join a column of a table that is an Integer type with a column of another table that is a BigInteger type? If so, would I need to cast or add anything special?

Yes you can, since whether you use `JOIN` or a cartesian product (`SELECT … FROM table1,table2`), what you actually need is a condition that can be evaluated as **true**. For instance :

```
 SELECT table1.*,
        table2.*

   FROM table1
   JOIN table2
     ON table1.id = table2.id
```

In the very last row of this query, this condition will be verified to decide the inclusion of the candidate tuple. Most of the type, you'll have the benefit of an implicit cast, but you'll need to care by yourself about special cases.